# Calculate mean of certain rows for each group after group by Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe which records 2 parameters and time for many IDs. There are malfunction situations that all parameters are 0.0, but date exists, like row 5.

```
 0   id  Param1  Param2   date
 1   1   1.45    6.47     2014-09-01 
 2   1   2.84    66.7     2014-09-03 
 3   2   -0.21   30       2014-11-11
 4   2   9970    3.9      2014-12-09
 5   2   0.0     0.0      2014-12-31
 6   2   8.26    1.25     2015-05-19
 7   3   90.1    45.9     2014-09-01
 8   3   9.01    4.0      2014-10-05
```

Such malfunction situation occurs once and only once for every ID. I would like to calculate the mean of parameters that are 10 rows above and below the malfunction row of this ID, separately.

How should I do this? I attempted to use groupby to isolate each ID, but failed to locate the malfunction records of each ID group and do calculations separately for rows above and below.

The dataframe contains ~3000 IDs and 900,000,000 rows of records. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: For each id, if there are multiple rows where all parameters are zero, then how would you like to compute means. Would there be multiple means corresponding to each row with all params equal to zero?

Comment: There is only one zero-parameter row for each ID group.

Answer (score 1):

Check below code, if it provides desired output.
Note that I have used rolling window of 3 row considering smaller set of data.

**Data frame :**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
Idata= {'id':[1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3],'param1':[1.45,2.84,-0.21,9970,0,8.26,0,90.1,9.01],'param2':[6.47,66.7,30,3.9,0,1.25,0,45.9,4],'date':['01-09-2014','03-09-2014','11-11-2014','09-12-2014','31-12-2014','19-05-2015','01-09-2014','05-10-2014','05-11-2014'],}
df=pd.DataFrame(Idata)
```

**Code :**

```
dflist=df.loc[df['param1']==0].index.values.tolist()
dflist2=np.array([list(range(x-1,x+2)) for x in dflist]).ravel().tolist()
df3=df.loc[dflist2,:][['param1','param2']].rolling(3,center=True, axis=0).mean().drop_duplicates()
df_final=df3.loc[df['param1']==0]
```

**Output:**

```
index   param1  param2
4   3326.086667 1.716667
6   32.786667   15.716667
```

Comment: Replace 3 with 21 for mean of 10 rows above , ten rows below including malfunction row.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your responding! however method would be applied to a dataframe that contains almost 1,000,000,000 rows of data. Using rolling window to calculate every ten rows would be considerably time-consuming. Thanks for your help tho!

Comment: @hema , I have updated the code to only take +1 and -1 rows for each malfunction row to calculate mean. This way it will not process complete data frame for rolling mean. You can change the number as per your need (-10 , +10).

Comment: @hema , Does this answer your query?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! I am encountering issue that it stuck at the first row to calculate the mean and give NaN in values. This might caused by my data and I am still exploring. I believe your solution helps and I would accept it once I get it all works on my data. Thanks.

Comment: @hema
Can you share a subset of the data?
or similar sample data?

Comment: Hi I would like to but not allowed to.. thanks for your inspiration anyway!